# unrecognized selector sent to instance when populating a Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When i try to populate the tableview in my view controller i get this error: **[UITableViewCellContentView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet var citta: AutoCompleteTextField!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var locality : String = ""
    var Locali = [Locale(Name: "Prova1", Address: "Via Prova ,1", Citta: "Bologna",Photo: UIImage(named: "Fav")!),Locale(Name: "Prova1", Address: "Via Prova ,1", Citta: "Bologna",Photo: UIImage(named: "Fav")!),Locale(Name: "Prova1", Address: "Via Prova ,1", Citta: "Bologna",Photo: UIImage(named: "Fav")!),Locale(Name: "Prova1", Address: "Via Prova ,1", Citta: "Bologna",Photo: UIImage(named: "Fav")!)]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView!.delegate = self
        self.tableView!.dataSource = self
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks,error) -> Void in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error : " + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            if placemarks!.count > 0{
                let pm = placemarks![0]
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            }})
    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
    }
    func displayLocationInfo(placemarks: CLPlacemark)
    {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.citta.text = placemarks.locality!

    }
    func tableView(tableView : UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section : Int) -> Int{
        return Locali.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)->UITableViewCell{
        let myCellToReturn = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Local_Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Local_Cell
        myCellToReturn.Nome?.text = Locali[indexPath.row].Name
        myCellToReturn.Address?.text = Locali[indexPath.row].Address
        myCellToReturn.Imago = UIImageView(image: Locali[indexPath.row].Image)


        return myCellToReturn
    }
}
```

Locale is my custom object, and Local_Cell is my custom cell and this is the code:

```
import UIKit

class Local_Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var Nome: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var Imago: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var Address: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var Fav_Button: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var Menu_Button: UIButton!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }


}
```

I try everything, can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this line of code:

```
myCellToReturn.Imago = UIImageView(image: Locali[indexPath.row].Image)
```

`Imago` is an `IBOutlet` then why you are instantiating a new `UIImageView` and assigning it to `Imago`

Try this

```
myCellToReturn.Imago.image = Locali[indexPath.row].Image
```

Comment: Thank you!! I change that line, it runs with no problem, but the tableview is not populated, you can figure out why?

Comment: confirm `Locali` does have elements in it

Comment: have you implemented `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: it is initialized in the view controller, how can it be empty?

Comment: Yes, i have implemented it to return the heigth of the prototype page

Comment: i suppose your only option is to debug by placing break points, start by placing break points in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to mismatch of object name you are using in `array` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

You are setting the image name in the object `Photo` in the array but you are using the object name `Image` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

And also, as @Usama said you are initialising a new `UIImageView`. So, here no need to create a new `UIImageView` just assign the `image` to existing one.

Replace the code

```
myCellToReturn.Imago = UIImageView(image: Locali[indexPath.row].Image)
```

with

```
myCellToReturn.Imago.image = UIImage(named: Locali[indexPath.row].Photo)
```